# Django - Ajax call OK but python method not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to make an Ajax POST call on a django method in `views.py`, my ajax called is ok : [Ajax call 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daW0X.png)

The problem is that my method `get_elem` in `views.py` is not called, when I use debugger on that method the process doesn't stop on the breakpoints. (using Pycharm).

My ajax call is :

function call_elem(elem_id, elem_type) {

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajax({
    url : "get_elem/",
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    },
    type:'POST',
    dataType :'json',
    data : {
        elem_id : elem_id,
        elem_typ : elem_type
    }

}).done( function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Success !');
});
```

}

As you can see, I already have the csrf token from the cookie. The method in `views.py` is :

```
def get_elem(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('elem_id') and request.POST.get('elem_type'):
        elem_id = request.POST.get('elem_id')
        elem_type = request.POST.get('elem_type')
        if elem_type == 'GR' or elem_type == 'GRC':
            elem = Groupe.objects.get(elem_id)
            json.dumps(elem.__dict__)
else:
    elem = {"error":"error..."}

return JsonResponse(elem)
```

**EDIT**
The url in  `url.py` is :

```
url(r'^test/get_elem/$', views.get_elem, name='get_elem')
```

But instead of returning the element in JSON, I get as answer the HTML code of the page from where I'm making the ajax call.

I've already done an ajax call previously in this code, and got no problem, I have no clue why this time I can't access the method...

Tanks for your time.

Comment: Show your URL patterns, `urls.py` for `get_elem` view.

Comment: elem = Groupe.objects.get(elem_id)  - Is "Groupe" spelled correctly?

Comment: Yes, my model is `Groupe` (i'm french). But the method is not even called I think... The breakpoints didn't stopped

Comment: In AJAX your URL is `get_elem/` but in `urls.py` the patterns is `test/get_elem/`, try to use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag instead so you don't have to hardcode url pattern e.g. `url : "{% url 'get_elem' %}"`

Comment: You have `if request.method == "GET":` in your views.py and `type:'POST',` in your javascript?

Comment: I'm in a separated file for my JS so I can't use the `{% %}` from Django template, but my url is good, I've tried with other and got errors. The get_elem is added to the url of the current page that is `http://localhost:8000/Syc/test/`

Comment: Changed that for some test, switched back to POST on both sides but no effect.